# preecher array, struct em C?

Tags: c, array, struct

como faço para preencher `leds` e `seq` sem precisar de um loop `for`?

```
int main()
{
    struct ledvalue
    {
        int seq[10]; 
        int leds[10]; 
    };


  struct ledvalue numbers;
  numbers.seq={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  numbers.leds={2,5,5,4,5,6,3,7,6,6};
}
```

queria preencher-los com os numeros porque depois vou precisar comparar `inputs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os valores forem fixos, você pode usar um literal de estrutura:

```
struct ledvalue numbers = {
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    { 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6, 6 }
};
```

Se não forem, não tem como: é *loop*, mesmo; ou você pode usar `memcpy()`, mas pra vetores desse tamanho, ela provavelmente faz uso de um *loop*.